# appendChild to the side or right

Tags: javascript, loops, append

I am using appendChild to show new sets of `div` but it is just added below. Is there a way to get it to the right or left side?

```js
for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {

  let courseName = data[i].name;
  let courseid = data[i]._id;
  let desc = data[i].description;
  let isActive = data[i].isActive;
  let id = document.getElementById("divHolder");
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div")
  if (isActive === true) {
    isActive = 'Active'
  } else {
    isActive = 'Inactive'
  }

  newDiv.innerHTML = `<div>this content to append</div>`
  id.prepend(newDiv);

}
```

Comment: You'll need CSS for this.

Answer (score 0):

Give your div an id using `Element.setAttribute`, and then move it to the left or right using CSS.

```js
for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {

  let courseName = data[i].name;
  let courseid = data[i]._id;
  let desc = data[i].description;
  let isActive = data[i].isActive ? "Active" : "Inactive";
  let container = document.getElementById("divHolder");
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute("id", "new-div");
  
  newDiv.innerHTML = `<div>this content to append</div>`
  container.prepend(newDiv);

}
```

```css
#new-div {
  float: right;
}
```